# How to delete leading zeroes?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, preg-replace

I have a column within a database I am using called last_count that is filled with int's. The number have the basic format of a lot of 0's and then the actual number (ex. 000001489). I need to get rid of the zeros before the number and then display them in a table generated from the query 'select last_count, query, job_id from twitterinblack46.job where job_id in ('.$job_id_all.') order by last_count desc;'

I was looking into preg_replace but then it also deleted other zeros (ex. if the number was 00001480, it echoed 148 instead of 1480). I am using php.

Comment: Out of curiousity...why is last_count zero-filled?

Comment: I'm not sure, I only have access to the database. I did not create it.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is to cast the value as an integer:

```
select cast(col as int)
```

This will display the number without the leading zeros.

If you need the value as a string, you can cast it back as a varchar:

```
select cast(cast col as int) as varchar(255))
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it through php and not another sql query because my query I am trying to display already has three other columns being displayed.

Comment: @Pstivala7 . . . Just replace the column in your query with the expression `cast(cast <col> as int) as varchar(255)) as <col>` where `<col>` is the specific column name.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the type to int in php

```
// Your sql stuff
$stmt->bind_result($last_count);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".intval($last_count)."</td>";  // Or use (int)$last_count
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

see http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
preg_match("/[^0].*/",$number, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

Comment: Run correctly for almost all cases, but if the given number is either 0 or negative, it returns a blank string and the absolute value of the negative number respectively